# Access NSMutableArray in another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I'm can see that there is a lot of questions regarding this already, but none of them seems to have given me an explanation to why I cannot access my array from another class.

Here's where I wan't to access the array
(XYZPaymentViewController.m)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    XYZMateOverviewViewController *test = [[XYZMateOverviewViewController alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *t = test.mates;
    NSLog(@"Count of ThatArray: %d", [t count]);
}
```

Nomatter what - the log writes out 0 !!

In another class (XYZMateOverviewViewController.h) I declare the array

```
@property (retain) NSMutableArray *mates;
```

I synthesize the array in the implementation area in XYZMateOverviewViewController.m

```
@synthesize mates;
```

I hope you can help me understand what I'm doing wrong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access an array from another ViewController you have to pass the array between the ViewControllers.

For example:

You have two ViewControllers. 'A' and 'B', so u have to do this:

In the 'A' ViewController, is where you have the array that you want to send to another ViewController. Then create an instance of 'B' ViewController and send the array to him:

CODE OF 'A' ViewController:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayToSend = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    BViewController *bViewController = [[BViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"BViewController" bundle:nil];

    BViewController.arrayReceived = arrayToSend;

[self.view addSubView:BViewController.view];
```

After, in your BViewController you just have to take your arrayReceived and use it.

CODE OF 'B' ViewController:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [arrayReceived objectAtIndex:0]); // For example.
```

Hope i did help you, if u have any question tell me.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It made a lot of sense to me. I am working in storyboard, so I could not use initWithNibName - but found out I could use instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier instead

Answer (score 1):

What are you doing with the mates array in the XYZMateOverviewViewController init method?

If you're not adding any data to it a count of 0 is just right.

Comment: I'm adding data to the array in XYZMateOverviewViewController.m

Comment: At which point in the code? You're creating a whole new instance of the object there.

Answer (score 1):

With the line

```
XYZMateOverviewViewController *test = [[XYZMateOverviewViewController alloc] init];
```

you are creating a *completely new* instance of XYZMateOverviewViewController—one that has nothing to do with any other part of your application*. What you should be doing instead is getting a reference to the already-set-up instance of the view controller. That instance presumably has its `mates` property set up with the data you want.

The general topic of sharing data between different parts of your application—and between different view controllers, in particular—should be covered somewhere toward the beginning of any “introduction to iOS programming” book or tutorial.

---

* Unless you’re doing something funky with singletons or shared state, of course, but I doubt that’s the case here.

Comment: Ok, maybe I'm doing it all wrong - the code you are referring to is just what I read would work in other similar questions.. But thanks, I'll find some tutorials :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you alloc/init the mutable array in the init method?

Comment: No, could that be what I'm missing?

Comment: Ahem... Yes. No alloc, no array. No addObject, no items in the array. Objects don't just appear by themselves, someone has to create them.